# Make select in client

Tags: python

I am doing a project in python about trivia with client and server and I'm using pycharm. 
The problem is with the client that when I am trying to connect and Display that I have connected to the server it stop responding. I am trying to do select for the client so it won't crush but I am not sure how to write it. I understand how to write the select in the server but it's not working in the client.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue if you would like some help.

Comment: Further to @Toby, please read [ask].